# JavaScript arrays and understanding arr[arr.length]

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is meant by `arr[arr.length]`. I mean what it really means or what it really does, I cannot understand the logic of how it works. Can anybody explain?

Comment: `arr[arr.length]` is the element after the last element. You can use it to add an element similar to `arr.push`.

Comment: see: [array.push(element) vs array\[array.length\] = element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952605/array-pushelement-vs-arrayarray-length-element)

Answer (score 2):

`arr.length` means the length of the array that spans from index `0` to `arr.length - 1`.

For instance if you got `arr = ["a", "b", "c"]`, `arr.length` is `3`.

`arr[0]` is `"a"`, `arr[1]` is `"b"` and `arr[2]` is `"c"`.

`arr[3]` does not exist, *yet*. but if you do `arr[arr.length] = "d"`, you obtain `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`.

This is an odd construction and usually, one should simply write `arr.push("d")`.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(arr.length, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
arr[arr.length] = "d";
console.log(arr);
arr.push("e");
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't describe the advantages of `arr[arr.length]`. Why would someone use `arr[arr.length]`?

Comment: There is not advantage. This is old code/old habit

Comment: Of course there is an advantage. `arr[arr.length] = b` returns `b`. You can write `() => arr[arr.length] = b` in one statement, e.g. for a random generator with memory `() => numbers[numbers.length] = Math.random()`

Comment: So if you had the answer, why asking in comments and not propose an edit of the answer?

Comment: People should think about their answer and invest some time. I didn't have the time.

Answer (score 1):

This statement gets the index of the last index of the array plus one. It is used to append items to an array. Equivalent to [`array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"];
// appends grapes to the array
fruits[fruits.length] = "grapes";
console.log(fruits);
```

For further reading, check out [MDN's page on array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods).

Comment: `array.push()` appends a value to an array.

Comment: This answer doesn't describe the advantages of `arr[arr.length]`. Why would someone use `arr[arr.length]`?

Comment: @jabaa I'm not sure if there are any advantages or disadvantages to using this method as opposed to `array.push()`. I'll do some research and try to figure it out.

Comment: Simple isn't always best

Comment: `arr[arr.length] = b` returns `b`. You can write `() => arr[arr.length] = b` in one statement, e.g. for a random generator with memory `() => numbers[numbers.length] = Math.random()`

Comment: @jabaa You can just as easily write the number generator like this:

`() => numbers[numbers.push(Math.random()) - 1]` so I'm not sure that's any different.

Answer (score 0):

`arr.length` is the length of the array.

`arr[arr.length]` is accessing by index the array length (out of bounds as length starts at 1, not index 0).

example:

```
const test = [1,2,3]
test[test.length]
undefined
test[test.length-1]
3
```

Comment: This answer doesn't describe the advantages of `arr[arr.length]`. Why would someone use `arr[arr.length]`?

Comment: I see literally no good reason to use it in JavaScript, but I'm happy to hear some if there are.

Comment: I prefer `() => numbers[numbers.length] = Math.random()` over `() => numbers[numbers.push(Math.random()) - 1]` but obviously it's just an opinion. I see no good reason to force `push` and use the returned length to access the array instead of directly using the value. For me it looks like writing bad code to force "good habits"

Comment: I think the fact that it is accessing an out of bounds index is reason enough, but I also find the push more readable because it always and only means adding a new item to the array, whereas reassigning an index is typically an update rather than insert operation. We're completely off topic from the original question, though. :)

Also, this was linked under the original question if you're curious about efficiency, although the difference is trivial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952605/array-pushelement-vs-arrayarray-length-element

Answer (score 0):

It just requests specific index of the array, Use case: Not very elegant way of adding new element to the array, like:

```
arr[arr.length] = newVal
arr.push(newVal)
arr = [...arr, newVal]
```

Comment: This answer doesn't describe the advantages of `arr[arr.length]`. Why would someone use `arr[arr.length]`?

Comment: @jabaa why u think there is any advantage at all? I mean- what's special about accessing an array by index? Getting anything more than that out of it, like one line hacks are just anti-patterns that makes codebase unsustainable.

Comment: Elegant is an opinion. For me something like `() => numbers[numbers.length] = Math.random()` is much more elegant than `() => { numbers.push(Math.random); return numbes[numbers.length - 1]; }`

Comment: @jabaa but you need to store numbers somewhere anyway, right? So even if this code looks still super ugly, it is way more clear what it does:
`() => array.push(Math.random()) && array.at(-1)`, but anyway, as I said, if you plan to use it in any bigger project, then again: this code is unsustainable

Comment: `arr.push(newVal)` is more sustainable than `arr[arr.length] = newVal` because why exactly? Elegance is an opinion. What advantages do you have with `arr.push(newVal)`?

Comment: @jabaa 
no advantage at all. However if you learn to do something in ugly way, you might eventually end up with:
`() => aParticularlyLongAndObnoxiousNameForIllustrativePurposes[aParticularlyLongAndObnoxiousNameForIllustrativePurposes.length] = newVal`

Comment: And `() => aParticularlyLongAndObnoxiousNameForIllustrativePurposes.push(Math.random()) && aParticularlyLongAndObnoxiousNameForIllustrativePurposes.at(-1)` is less ugly for you?